# How to run this command with cygwin

Tags: cygwin

How can I run this Unix command `. ./filename.sh` with cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

Open up your `Start` menu, select the `Cygwin` submenu and click on `Cygwin Bash Shell`. That gives you a UNIX-oriented shell in which it'll be a lot easier to do UNIXy type things, like running whatever script you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that command is not so much bound to a platform (if you allow that term for Cygwin) as it is a *shell* intrinsic/builtin. In Bash (to my knowledge default shell in Cygwin), for example, those two lines are equivalent:

```
. ./filename.sh
source ./filename.sh
```

All variables, exported or not, will be integrated into your current shell instance (unless enclosed in parentheses, i.e. assignments done in subshells).